# Show $\sum_{k \geq 0}\binom{n}k \left((-1)^k+1\right)x^k = 2\sum_{k \geq 0}\binom{n}{2k}x^{2k}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, combinatorial-proofs

Hello I am trying to understand the following proof:

$$\begin{align*}
(1-x)^n+(1+x)^n &= \sum_{k \geq 0}\binom{n}k (-1)^kx^k + \sum_{k \geq 0} \binom{n}k x^k\\
&= \sum_{k \geq 0}\binom{n}k \left((-1)^k+1\right)x^k\\
&= 2\sum_{k \geq 0}\binom{n}{2k}x^{2k}\\
&< 2\sum_{k \geq 0}\binom{n}{2k}\tag{1}\\
&= 2\cdot 2^{n-1}\tag{2}\\
&= 2^n,
\end{align*}$$

But I do not understand why $$\sum_{k \geq 0}\binom{n}k \left((-1)^k+1\right)x^k
= 2\sum_{k \geq 0}\binom{n}{2k}x^{2k}.$$
Can someone explain this part? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: What happens with the terms when $k$ is an odd number?

Comment: @Gary it becomes $-1+1$ which gives you 0. I guess the odd case for $k$ is trivial. So we just consider the even cases. But I still not understand why $k$ stays the same variable. instead of $2k$ it should not be $k=2m$ where m is a positive integer?

Comment: Yo are right. It is better to change the symbol from $k$ to something else. The author of the proof was a little bit sloppy.

Comment: @Gary: It is not sloppy. An index of summation is a kind of dummy variable that need not mean the same thing in different summations in an expression, and the displayed equality is perfectly correct: the expressions are equal. Similarly, it is perfectly correct to write $\sum_{k\ge 1}x^{k-1}=\sum_{k\ge 0}x^k$, even though the two indices of summation are not even running over the same set of values.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ok, sloppy was an overstatement. It could be useful to have a different symbol sometimes to help the reader. The OP got confused with thisone.

Answer (score 2):

Because $$\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}=\begin{cases}1 &\text{if $k$ is even}\\0 &\text{if $k$ is odd}\end{cases}$$
we have more generally
$$\sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2} a_k = \sum_{k \ge 0} a_{2k}.$$
Your identity is the case $a_k=\binom{n}{k}x^k$.